# Java - Grouping repeated chars in a String

Tags: java, string, count, character

(This is not homework)
We have some extra exercices we can do, and i have done some.
But i got stuck in this one...
I need to make a program that given the string "loool" prints "l:1:o:3:l:1".
I have tried a bunch of combinations but i keep getting the same problem:
- I cant make the last repeated letter to get print ( Because with my code  the next char needs to be different for a print to occurr).

```
        String str = "loool";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    int count = 1;  
    char before;
    before = str.charAt(0);

    for (int i = 1;i < str.length();i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == before) {
            count++;
        }
        else {
            sb.append(before + ":" + count);
            before = str.charAt(i);
            count = 1;
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
```

Comment: so another stop condition is the end of the string not just a different next char

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add some logic after your loop has finished, in order to deal with this problem.  This logic will probably be very similar to the some of the code that you're using in the `else` block.

Comment: Got it.
I wanted to do it all inside the for() never thought in adding stuff after the loop.